# Check if username or email exist in mongodb atlas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

Im new to MERN. I want to print USER ALREADY EXIST if email or name already present. I used .find method but its not working. here,s the code

```
    const { response } = require('express')
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const User = mongoose.model("User") 'defined in user.js'
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
    
    
    router.post('/signup',(req,res)=>{
        const {name,email,password} = req.body
        if(!email || !password || !name){
           return res.status(422).json({"error":"please add all the fields"}) //status 422 means server has understood the request but cant proess 
        }
    
       User.find({email : email, name : name}).then((savedUser)=>{
           if(savedUser){
               return res.status(422).json({error:"user already exist."})
           }
    
           bcrypt.hash(password,6).then(hashedpassword=>{
            const user = new User({
                email,    //is also written as "email" : email
                password:hashedpassword,
                name
            })
     
            user.save().then(user=>{
                res.json({message:"saved sucessfully"})
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })  
           }) /
        
       }).catch(err=>{
           console.log(err)
       })
    
    }) 
    
    
    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `User.find({email : email, name : name})` will only match if both the name and email exactly match in the document.  Was that the intent?

Answer (score 1):

Using `.find()` in mongoose returns array of documents, even if there is one record it will be inside an array. The problem is when no document matches your query `.find()` will return an empty array. making `savedUser = []` and when you check it in here `if(savedUser)` it always returns true, resulting in
below block to always run

```
return res.status(422).json({error:"user already exist."})
```

You can overcome this problem either by using:

1. `if(savedUser.length)` (checking there are items in array).
2. or by using `.findOne` instead of `.find` which will return first document matching you query and `null` otherwise.

I would suggest using `.findOne`